# In android/app/build.gradle - following errors occur: following errors occur, following errors occur, following errors occur! How to fix?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-plugin

I am developing apps flutter, but an error has been occurring in all my projects, even if I have just started, the error is already there, they do not affect the compilation but I'm afraid they are future problems!
Can someone help me correct?

```
    def localProperties = new **Properties**()
    def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
        if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
            localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
            localProperties.load(reader)
       }
   }

   def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
    if (flutterRoot == null) {
       throw new **GradleException**("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
   }

   def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
   flutterVersionCode = '3001'


    def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
    flutterVersionName = '0.0.3'


    def keystoreProperties = new **Properties**()
    def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
     if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new **FileInputStream**(keystorePropertiesFile))
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These aren't the actual errors, currently you are opening these files in Flutter, so you see the error.

All you need to do is open `build.gradle(app)`, and on top right corner of your IDE you should see something like:

[image]

Once you launch it in Android Studio as android module, you'll see errors are gone!

Comment: Thank you so much for the sclerosis! I'm new to flutter development ...